# Filter for Google Docs to display colored row

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I am using Google spread sheet as my bug sheet,i have mark some bugs as fixed and had highlighted that row with some color ,know i want to see all those fixed bugs row .how can i apply filter for it?

Comment: Google-apps-script will read/write Cell colors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. Do you want to make it so that the cell turns a different color if a certain text, such as "Error", or "Fixed" is entered in? If so, go to where you change the background or text color in the menu, go to "Conditional Formatting", and enter in the rule

Text Contains: Error.  Format: Background color(and change it to the color you want)

Then click "Add Rule" and Do the same thing, except instead of Error, you put fixed. If you do this, then click the box in the bottom right corner of the cell you have just edited, then drag it down to all the cells you want the conditional formatting to occur, every time you enter in either "Fixed" or "Error", it will turn the color you want it to.

If you are trying to sort the row by what is fixed or not, then I suggest you add another column that says "Fixed" or "Still Bugged". After you do this, create another tab at the bottom of the spreadsheet. Once you have done that, enter in `=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:F20, "Order by E")`

In that formula, the A1:F20 is the table you have if it is debugged, the link, the name, or whatever you have in the table. The Column E is the column in which you have that says if it is fixed or not. Sheet1 the sheet that has all of your data in it.

Hope I could help!